# Material Preview not showing any color

Tags: eevee-render-engine

[image]

This is my first time using Blender. It's just really annoying because I have to go into render mode just to check the color.

And here is the render mode:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the *Lighting* options in the *Viewport Shading* panel, it should be deactivated in *Material* preview mode and activated in *Rendered* preview mode, *Scene Lights* activates the lights you've set and *Scene World* activates the world material:

[image]

Comment: Hi there, when i checked it and it become weird

Comment: Could you please share your file as it was when you asked your question? It may be a problem of graphic card...

Comment: yeah its probably the graphics card i'm using AMD btw.

Comment: Oh ok it may explain, maybe try a previous driver?